# Why can’t we write $\overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot \overrightarrow{M} = \chi_m \overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot\overrightarrow{H}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

We know that $\overrightarrow{B} = \mu_0 (\overrightarrow{H} + \overrightarrow{M})$.

$\therefore \overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot\overrightarrow{B} = \mu_0 (\overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot\overrightarrow{H} + \overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot\overrightarrow{M})$

$\implies \overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot \overrightarrow{M} = -\overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot\overrightarrow{H} \tag{1}$

But for a linear media $\overrightarrow{M} = \chi_m \overrightarrow{H}$.

$\therefore$ why can’t we take the divergence and write $\overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot \overrightarrow{M} = \chi_m \overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot\overrightarrow{H}? \tag{2}$

If one says equation $(2)$ is valid, then $\chi_m = -1$, which is not valid. So, how what mistake have I made?

Comment: If $\chi_m$ is constant (as you assume), then $\vec\nabla \cdot \vec M = \vec\nabla \cdot \vec B= \vec\nabla \cdot \vec H =0$.

Comment: Of course you can take the divergence of both sides of a vector equation as long as it is  in an open domain where the vector fields are differentiable.  The operation fails to hold where you have a jump condition, i.e, at the boundary between an ideal diamagnetic material and free space, there you have poles.